# Update query to copy one column data to another fails

Tags: mysql, sql

Following query gives error 1064. Why?

```
update projects 
set project_renewal = select project_renewal from Project_number;
```

I tried this

```
update projects 
set project_renewal = (select project_renewal from Project_number)
```

Then it gives error 1242. Subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: The sub query returns multiple rows as output. YOu should use "where" clauselike: select project_renewal from Project_number WHERE ID = 1000

Answer (score 1):

You probably need some sort of correlation clause:

```
update projects p
set project_renewal = (select project_renewal
                       from Project_number pn
                       where pn.<column> = p.<column>
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
update projects 
set project_renewal = (select project_renewal from Project_number ORDER BY project_renewal LIMIT 1);
```

This will give you one row, but you should also use a where Clause to determine which project_renewal you want

Comment: It is adding 0 to all the column values. I need the whole column Project_number.project_renewal to be copied to projects.project_renewal

Comment: What column can be used to join both tables besides project_renewal ?

Comment: None, simply copying values from column A to column B.

Comment: That is not possilble, at least not without giving them a ranking and join by the ranking.. Post please the create table for both

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon says, you need to match the rows in your target table with your source (project_number) data:

```
update projects p
set project_reneval = q.project_reneval
from project_number q
left join projects r on r.project_number = q.project_number
```

assuming both tables contain the common project number column